# Безличное сказуемое + будущее время

Tags: грамотная-речь, сказуемые, времена, тип-сказуемого

"Этого не хочется будет делать".

Фраза звучит, но похоже, грамматически некорректна, не находите? В чем некорректность и как будет правильно?

Comment: Будет такое, что этого не хочется делать - вот правильный вариант данной конструкции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Этого не хочется будет делать". Эта фраза **вообще не звучит**. В ней смешано настоящее и будущее время ("будет не хочется").

Грамматически правильные варианты:

*Этого не хочется делать.

Этого делать не захочется.

Этого делать не будет хотеться.

Этого делать будет не хотеться.*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142826/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.